# 2 partitions in a sharded mysql database

Tags: database, memory, sharding

the first one is running at 73% memory utilization. The second one runs at 16% utilization.

how can i balance the 2 out?

Answer (score 0):

Design your sharding better so that it divides the records into pools of roughly equal utilization?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you repartition them.

Get some more data as to how the data is used on each server and try to move some records to the less used server.